# Ocaml's `try ... with` in Haskell

Tags: haskell, exception, ocaml

My question: is there any "try with" equivalent in Haskell? Something like this :

```
try 
{
 head l
}
with 
Failure _ -> []
```

If the operation in try failed we pattern match the error and do appropriate job in with section?

Comment: There's [spoon](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/spoon-0.3.1/docs/Control-Spoon.html), but this is pretty hackish and not reliable in a multithreaded context. The preferred thing to do is to avoid partial functions, or if you use them then first perform a sanity check on the arguments to make sure no exception is ever thrown.

Answer (score 3):

You should really be avoiding such errors via total functions. Then, if a function can return an error, have its return type be an `Either e a` where `e` is the type of the exception and `a` is the otherwise successful type. If you don't need to pass any information about the exception, you can just return `Maybe a`.

That said, [`Control.Exception`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.9.0.0/docs/Control-Exception.html) has some facilities for catching errors via `try` or `catch`, at the cost of only being able to do such handling in the `IO` monad. At GHCi you can see this:

```
ghci> import Control.Exception
ghci> catch (head []) (\msg -> putStrLn $ "caught: " ++ show (msg :: SomeException))
caught: Prelude.head: empty list
```

Comment: I don't want to show the message I want to run another function and I just bring this example to make it simple.

Comment: Well you can do any inside the function you pass to `catch`... But if that is what you are doing, you really need to be using total functions instead. Take a look at the other answer for an example of that.

Answer (score 2):

You can use functions and total functions to achieve the same thing most of the time. For your example:

`fromMaybe [] (listToMaybe l)`

Comment: ...or in this case simply `take 1`.

Answer (score 0):

In this simple case, you could just use `foldr`:

```hs
foldr const [] l
```

Or even use pattern matching directly:

```
case l of
  [] -> []
  x : _ -> x
```

More generally, using `Maybe` or `Either`, as others have suggested, can make for more modular code. You may want to check out the `MaybeT` and `ExceptT` types, and the `MonadError` class, to integrate failure into monadic computations.